# How do people usually implement jsonp in python?

Tags: python, api, jsonp

I would like to learn how to use jsonp with python. I googled around for any useful tutorial. However, it seems that there are no so much resources up there.

Thus I would like to ask here if anybody knows any tutorial, API that I can use, or any best practices.

Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you mean supporting the *generation* of JSOP output with a Python-powered API or website?

That's pretty easy to support. Say your API at `/some/resource.json` already outputs some JSON encoded data (say, in the code it's a `return json.dumps(dict(a='foo'))`).

To support JSONP all you have to do is accept a callback parameter (say `/some/resource.json&callback=some_func`). Now, if you get this parameter, instead of returning just the json serialized data, you wrap it in a function call:

```
  d = json.dumps(dict(a='foo'))
  return 'some_func(' + d + ');'
```

That way, calling web-client code can simply auto insert script tags in its DOM to magically load your javascript 'function'. Make sense?

Comment: Thank you so much rlotun. I have one more small question here. What does tiddlywebplugins.jsonp play in this context, does it just wrap up the returned json data with 'some_func' function call when it sees the 'callback=some_func' parameter passed in?

Comment: Taking a look at that `tiddlywebplugins` thing - it almost literally implements the above, with specific hooks to the framework it's plugging into.